# Error using source in Puppet manifest

Tags: puppet

I am trying to change a file in puppet agents and I have written the below code.

```
modules/
├── helloworld
│   └── manifests
│       ├── init.pp
│       └── motd.pp
└── ssh
    ├── manifests
    |    └── init.pp
    └── ssh_config
```

my Puppet manifest code:

```
# modules/ssh/manifests/init.pp 
class ssh {
  package { 'openssl':
    ensure => present,
    before => File['/etc/ssh/sshd_config'],
  }

  file {'ssh_config':
    ensure => file,
    path   => '/etc/ssh/sshd_config',
    mode   => "600",
    source => "puppet:///modules/ssh/ssh_config",
  }

  service {'sshd':
    ensure    => running, 
    enable    => true,
    subscribe => File['/etc/ssh/sshd_config'],
  }
}
```

Below is the main manifest's code:

```
# manifests/site.pp 
node default {
  class { 'ssh': }
}
```

Below is the error I am receiving:

```
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for dheera.asicdesigners.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1478497316'
Error: /Stage[main]/Ssh/File[ssh_config]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production        source(s)       
puppet:///modules/ssh/ssh_config
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ssh/Service[sshd]: Dependency File[ssh_config] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Ssh/Service[sshd]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.21 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ssh_config` file location needs to be in the `files` directory of your module to be used with the Puppet URI in the `source` attribute like you are doing.

```
modules/
├── helloworld
│   └── manifests
│       ├── init.pp
│       └── motd.pp
└── ssh
    ├── manifests
    |    └── init.pp
    └── files
         ├── ssh_config
```

Also, you probably meant your `package` resource to be `openssh` and not `openssl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Matt it works . Above is the just example i am trying

Comment: @sagar Good to hear. Please accept my answer if it was helpful.